# Как вообще может работать класс Runnable?

Tags: многопоточность, java

Мне тут стало интересно, что же представляет из себя интерфейс Runnable. Честно сказать, я удивлен. Вот весь его код:

```
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Но я ведь тоже могу написать такой интерфейс:

```
public interface NewThread {
    public abstract void go();
}
```

Но он не будет работать (или будет?). Объясните, пожалуйста, как же это все работает?

Comment: Гм. А что вы ещё ожидали увидеть в интерфейсе?

Comment: Вот тут то и наступает когнитивный диссонанс. Логикой понимаешь, что ничего, но не понимаешь, как оно вообще тогда работает))

Comment: Работает оно очень просто. Код получает некий класс, имплементирующий `Runnable`, и знает, что у того, согласно внешнему контракту, имеется и реализован метод `run`, стало быть, он может совершенно спокойно вызвать этот метод. А уже класс, имплементирующий интерфейс `Runnable`, помещает в этот метод какую-то логику. Какой именно момент вам не до конца понятен?

Comment: Я думаю, автору стоить почитать про интерфейсы маркеры, как вариант. Жава машина не весь код интерпретирует одинаково, просто скопировать название не поможет, определенные вещи спрятаны от наших глаз.

Comment: @Cooler, какое отношение имеют маркерные интерфейсы к `Runnable`?

Comment: @qwoort, выше сказано очень правильное слово - контракт. Интерфейс - это такое связующее звено между компонентами, которое говорит: да, компонент, я готов с тобой работать. Интерфейсы не могут проследить, вызывается ли внутри необходимое поведение, но они существуют не для этого, а именно для объявления этой взаимосвязи. Когда человек будет использовать этот интерфейс, его целью будет не реализовать `run()` как-нибудь, а выполнить вполне конкретный код, **точкой запуска которого будет run()**.

Comment: falstaf, вот я и хочу разобраться с тем, что спрятано (как пишет Coolre) от наших глаз. Быть может, кто-то подскажет? Почему в моем примере JVM созданный мной класс воспринимает не так как Runnable?

Comment: @qwoort, в данном случае ничего не спрятано, и всё вполне очевидно.

> Почему в моем примере JVM созданный мной класс воспринимает не так, как Runnable?

Очевидно, потому, что вызываемый код ожидает именно `Runnable`?

Comment: @falstaf, нет, я хочу понять, где прописано, что именно класс с названием Runnable должен вызывать дополнительный поток. Ведь это где-то прописано?

Comment: @qwoort, это прописано [в конструкторах класса Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

В том конструкторе, который все обычно используют (`Thread(new MyThreadClass)`), написано, что у `MyThreadClass` д.б. *тип Runnable*.

Вот, собственно, и все. Т.е. все эти слова нужны лишь для проверок компилятором "правильности" программы.

--

Реально поток запускается на исполнение **вызовом метода `.start()`** экземпляра класса Thread, который в свою очередь вызывает метод с сигнатурой `public void run()` в экземпляре класса, который был передан в конструктор Thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вся магия расположена в классе `Thread`. Он реализует всё, что нужно, и ему только надо запустить какой-то код. Как ему это сделать?

С лямбдами сейчас проще — передали лямбду без аргументов и без возвращаемого значения, и её можно запускать. А что делать было до Java 8? Нужно что-то запустить. Что это может быть в принципе? Поскольку функцию в thread невозможно, можно передать только экземпляр класса (в Java всё — классы, помните?). А как гарантировать, что у этого класса будет метод без аргументов и без возвращаемого значения?

Разные языки подходят по-разному. Некоторые используют duck typing: пусть в классе будет один метод, его и запускать. Или передача по имени: передать ещё и имя метода, его и запускать. Но эти методы очень не в духе Java: duck typing не используется в Java нигде, а рефлексия не гарантирует, что скомпилированный код будет работать.

А вот интерфейс — хорошее решение. Но какой интерфейс использовать? Взять готовый — ну так у интерфейса должен быть смысл. Вот и придумали интерфейс Runnable: он лишь декларирует, что у класса есть метод `run`. Его thread и запустит.

Если вы напишете свой интерфейс, откуда thread о нём узнает? Поэтому-то ваш аналог Runnable и не проходит. Хотя в принципе ничего не мешало бы, будь система типов Java [structural, а не nominal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_and_structural_type_systems) (как это по-русски?).

---

Короче: разработчикам Java нужен был какой-то путь убедиться, что у переданного класса есть метод без аргументов и возвращаемого значения. Вот они чисто формально и определили интерфейс. «Особость» этого интерфейса только в том, что о нём знает `Thread`, и берёт из него метод.

Comment: Спасибо) Тогда получается, что нет разницы, имплементировать Интерфейс или наследовать класс?

Comment: @qwoort: По большому счёту это одно и то же.

Но: наследовать класс означает, что вам, кроме абстрактных методов, может прийти ещё куча готовых методов, которые вы, может быть, вовсе и не хотели. А если вы имплементируете интерфейс, то точно ничего «левого» там нет.

Поэтому принято использовать интерфейс там, где надо просто убедиться в наличии методов. А абстрактный класс обычно используют там, где надо вынести общий код в базовый класс (то есть для повторного использования кода).

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно ценный комментарий!

Comment: @qwoort, может быть, для понимания сути интерфейса будет полезно думать о нем, просто как о фильтре (или маске), через который видна (и при этом обязательно должна существовать) только часть методов и полей класса. Причем через один и тот же интерфейс можно "смотреть" на разные классы.

Компилятор же, обрабатывая описание интерфейса, никакого нового кода для jvm не создает (в отличие от класса).

В общем, еще один способ инкапсуляции (возможно, по началу это неочевидно) или  замена множественного наследования, которого нет в Java (более общепринятая точка зрения).

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку комментарии кончились, отвечаю здесь.

> нет, я хочу понять, где прописано, что именно интерфейс с названием Runnable должен вызывать дополнительный поток. Ведь это где-то прописано?

Я так понимаю, речь идёт о `java.lang.Thread`? Ну так в его сорцы и посмотрите. Всё же просто. [Наслаждайтесь](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java).

Comment: Спасибо, но речь конкретно об интерфейсе Runnable. Я не могу понять, как, грубо говоря, пустой класс реализует такую сложную штуку как многопоточность...

Comment: Да не реализует он ничего. И не класс это вовсе. Это интерфейс. Публичный контракт то бишь. И ничего более. Это уже `Thread` и прочие реализуют многопоточность. А в нужном месте дёргают `Runnable.run()`, который вы у себя и имплементируете.